# Gurobi constraints, list comprehension

Tags: constraints, list-comprehension, gurobi

I am unable to create a list of constraints in gurobi with list comprehension.

I made this able to work

```
m.addConstr(0_decision[0] + 1_decision[0] + 2_decision[0] + 3_decision[0] + 4_decision[0] + 5_decision[0] + 6_decision[0] , GRB.EQUAL, test_list[0])
```

However, I have too much data to enter manually, and substituting i in for the numbers does not work: This doesn't work

```
m.addConstrs([0_decision[i] + 1_decision[i] + 2_decision[i] + 3_decision[i] + 4_decision[i] + 5_decision[i] + 6_decision[i] for i in range(500)], GRB.EQUAL, test_list[i])
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: addConstrs() takes at most 3 positional arguments (4 given)
```

I tried different forms of comprehension, I tried to do it one at a time and that works! But I have too many I cannot afford to do it hundreds of times.

Answer (score 0):

Use a generator expression across the entire expression:

```
m.addConstrs(0_decision[i] + 1_decision[i] + 2_decision[i] +
             3_decision[i] + 4_decision[i] + 5_decision[i] + 
             6_decision[i] == test_list[i] for i in range(500))
```

Better yet, refactor the *_decision variables using Model.addVars() so that you can write:

```
m.addConstrs(decision.sum('*',i) == test_list[i] for i in range(500))
```